# Angular extend error handler cyclic error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to extend the angular `ErrorHandler` so that I can redirect my application to another component and do some logging.

I created the error handler like so:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(
        private injector: Injector,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    handleError(error) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
        //throw error;
    }
}
```

**app.module:**

```
providers:[ { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler } ]
```

When I try and load my application like this, I am getting the following error.

```
compiler.es5.js:11684 Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Router ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
```

It sounds like it is something to do with the `router` tat I am trying to import to be able to do the redirect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Consider what happens if there is an error in the `router`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
providers:[ { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler } ]
```

You should do this

```
providers:[ErrorHandler, GlobalErrorHandler]
```

It's just a simple Array

Hope it helps

Comment: I guess this will work too: providers:[GlobalErrorHandler]